# Interfacing strace with Process Name instead of PID

Tags: bash, process, pid, strace, trace

How do I implement a wrapper script `pstrace` in bash that changees the interface of

```
[sudo] strace -c -p [PID]
```

to

```
[sudo] pstrace -c -p [PROCESS-NAME]
```

similar to how

```
killall [PROCESS-NAME]
```

is used. With completion and everything.

Answer (score 0):

killall tabing is handled with bash-completion package at lease on ubuntu. You can see the script at

```
/etc/bash_completion.d/procps
```

You'd have to either find a script to drop in that directory or write your own. But for strace the -p is for a pid so not sure how well bash-completion would work.